# Can I disable the auto complete?

Tags: customization, autocomplete

I've recently upgraded to WordPress 3.0, and am having a lot of problems with the autocomplete function when editing posts via 'quick edit' (e.g. /wp-admin/edit.php) - for example, editing tags. The autocomplete box often obscures the textbox I'm trying to enter text into, and sometimes gets 'left behind' once the 'update' button has been clicked.

Is there a way to disable the autocomplete?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, this is a *Wordpress* autocomplete feature, not a *browser-based* one.

**UPDATE 2**

It looks as if I need to remove the 'suggest' argument to "load-scripts.php", referenced at the bottom of each admin page like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript'
  src='http://www.example.com/path/to/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load=hoverIntent,common,jquery-color,suggest,inline-edit-post'>
</script>
```

That seems to be generated by:

```
do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');
```

but I lose the code trail at that point - anyone?

Comment: Autocomplete is a feature of the browser itself, so knowing which browser (and which version) you're using would help ...

Comment: Are you sure it's WordPress autocomplete? Do you get a different result with a different browser?

Comment: Come to think of it, what browser are you seeing this behavior in?

Comment: Happens in both Firefox and IE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a solution I tested, and it works.

The autocomplete for the tags is currently done via an ajax request to the file admin-ajax.php.
The solution I would suggest is to block the processing of the request so that it does not return any result. I would do :

```
function no_tag_suggest() {
    if( DOING_AJAX == true && $_GET['action'] == 'ajax-tag-search' && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == admin_url( 'edit.php' ) ) {
        die;
    }
}    
add_action('admin_init', 'no_tag_suggest');
```

The previous function verify:

1. if it is an ajax request
2. if the action paramater is
   'ajax-tag-search'
3. if the referer url is the
   '/wp-admin/edit.php' page

If these 3 conditions are meet, no result will be returned and the tag suggestions not displayed.

If you want to remove this autocomplete from all the pages, not the 'wp-admin/edit.php' only, you can do:

```
function no_tag_suggest() {
    if( DOING_AJAX == true && $_GET['action'] == 'ajax-tag-search' ) ) {
        die;
    }
}    
add_action('admin_init', 'no_tag_suggest');
```

I would suggest you to look at the code of 'admin-ajax.php' to see all the 'action' parameters there, thus all the ajax requests you can kill with similar methods.

I hope my explanation was clear. Don't hesitate to ask me if you want more details or have any question.

Bounty for me? :)

Comment: This looks very close to an excellent answer, BUT ... it doesn't work for me. The values of the referrer and the admin url are the problem - the former is being reported with the query params (edit.php?post_type=post&) whilst the latter is just 'edit.php'. I've fixed that with a call to strpos() and a check on '=== 0', but if you can think of a better way, please include it. With that in place, it works - almost - perfectly.

Comment: There's still scope for someone to improve on this answer, although it's the best so far. Ideally, there would be a nice clean way of disabling the ajax request in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can either disable it in your browser or route around the WP source and slap this `autocomplete` attribute in the offending box:

```
<input autocomplete="off" />
```

Alternatively you could use greasemonkey to modify the page to disable autocomplete in the way mentioned above.

Comment: This is a wordpress autocomplete feature. Do you know if it inspects that property first, though?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin:

**Tag Uncomplete**

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tag-uncomplete/

Its intended for people who have a very large number of tag terms, but it does exactly what your wanting

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't appear to work. The plugin's quite old, and only mentions wordpress 2.5, so I'm guessing it's due an upgrade. The source is very simple, so I might be able to 'port' it over to wordpress 3 - will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a response from the server, [as sorich87 has explained](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137/can-i-disable-the-autocomplete/1380#1380), or you could try the (more complicated) way of disabling the javascript that starts the AJAX request. If you just remove [the `suggest` library](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/js/jquery/suggest.dev.js), the [various](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.dev.js#L104) [places](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/js/post.dev.js#L136) that call the `suggest` function will probably fail, so you should replace it with a stub function that does nothing.

Comment: I would, certainly, prefer to do that. However, it would be nice to do that in as clean a way as possible - currently, I feel sorich87's solution is less intrusive than renaming files, etc. The method used to load the suggest library REALLY implies there must be a nice flexible way of disabling it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `attr` in html element.

```
$('#register_username').attr('autocomplete','off');
```

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete *IS* a browser function but it is an Input field parameter.

If a website must meet PCI compliance standards it will FAIL PCI if autocomplete is on in the input fields--regardless of anyone's browser.