# Disable stored tags queries in admin page when posting a new post

Tags: jquery, taxonomy, query, tags

First of all, I am sorry because I am a bit newbie here and I am still learning forgive me, please.

I have a Wordpress website blog and I have a very big database of tags stored in MySQL the problem is whenever any admin try to add a tag i.e he type "fruit" WordPress is starting to look all over the database so it autocompletes it which has a massive amount of tags and then the whole MySQL server crash and I get a database error.

So my question is how I can disable the query action when adding a tag in admin post page using code?

I just want WordPress to stop querying the existing tags in the database because that really crash the whole server.

Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: Does the accepted answer of this question work for you? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137/can-i-disable-the-auto-complete  It is 10 years old... but worth a try.

Comment: @rank Thank you for your response, I've just tried this method and it's not working, the website is still crashing after searching in tags.